# FASTREPORT Adding objects dynamically in report script

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I try to add TLineView objects to a report.
The number of lines is depending on a certain number, retrieved by the reports dataset.

I have put my code into the scripts initialization part and in a very experimental test version it looks like this:

```
var nol, i: integer;
child, newChild: TfrxChild;
noteLine1, noteLine2: TfrxLineView;
page: TfrxPage;                                 
begin
  page := ReportName;                                                                 
  nol := <DS_MAIN."VOLUME"> /2;
  nol := nol + <DS_MAIN."VOLUME"> mod 2;
  child3.child := TfrxChild.create(nil);
  newchild := child3.child;
  newChild.Visible := true;                                                        
  noteLine1 := TfrxLineView.create(newChild);
  noteLine1.name := 'nl1000';                                                
  noteLine1.Top := 0.73;
  noteLine1.Width := 7.5;
  noteLine1.Left := 3;
  noteLine1.Visible := true;                                                          
  noteLine1.Parent.Objects.Remove(noteLine1);                                                                                                     
  noteLine1.Parent.Objects.Add(noteLine1);                                                                                                     
//  newChild.Objects.Add(noteLine1);
  noteLine2 := TfrxLineView.create(newChild);
  noteLine2.name := 'nl1001';                                                
  noteLine2.Top := 0.73;
  noteLine2.Width := 7.5;
  noteLine2.Left := 11.2;
  newChild.Objects.Add(noteLine2);                                                                                          
  noteLine2.Visible := true;                                                          

  for i := 1 to nol do begin
    Child := TfrxChild.create(nil);
    NewChild.child := Child;
    newChild := child;                                            
  end;
end.
```

Instead of getting two lines side by side, with a gap between them, I get only a single short line of a length of around 3-4 mm.

The above code is just a snap of my trial-and-error session.
Hope now that there could be anyone to give me some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my final solution:

```
procedure Child8OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var nol, i: integer;
left1, left2: extended;                               
child, newChild: TfrxChild;
noteLine1, noteLine2, line: TfrxLineView;
page: TfrxPage;
band: TfrxChild;                                   
begin
  nol := <DS_MAIN."VOLUME"> /2;
  nol := nol + <DS_MAIN."VOLUME"> mod 2;
   band := TfrxChild(TRP_ORDER_NOTE.FindObject('Child9'));
   // Lines generation
   left1 := 3*fr1cm;
   left2 := 11.2*fr1cm;
   for i := 1 to nol do begin
      line := TfrxLineView.Create(band);
      line.Name := 'noteLine'+intToStr(1+2*(i-1+trunc(random*1000000))); //Panic solution
      line.Top   := fr1cm*(0.73 + (i-1)*0.75);
      line.Width := 7.5*fr1cm;
      line.Left  := left1;
      if (<DS_MAIN."VOLUME"> mod 2 > 0 ) and (i = nol) then
        exit                                   
      else 
      begin
        line := TfrxLineView.Create(band);
        line.Name := 'noteLine'+intToStr(2*i+trunc(random*1000000));
        line.Top   := fr1cm*(0.73 + (i-1)*0.75);
        line.Width := 7.5*fr1cm;
        line.Left  := left2;
      end;                
   end;

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to consider at least the following:

- With your `for` loop you create bands, not lines. You may try to change the logic and create objects (memos, lines, shapes) with bands as owners.
- The objects’ coordinates and sizes are set in pixels, so you need an additional calculation.

From documentation:

> Objects’ coordinates and sizes are set in pixels. Since the «Left,»
> «Top,» «Width,» and «Height» properties of all objects have the
> «Extended» type, you can point out non-integer values. The following
> constants are defined for converting pixels into centimeters and
> inches:
>
> fr01cm = 3.77953;
> fr1cm = 37.7953;
> fr01in = 9.6;
> fr1in = 96;

The following working example generates five `TfrxLineView` objects. Just put an empty report on your form and add report title band:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnPreviewClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   nol, i: integer;
   left: Extended;
   band: TfrxReportTitle;
   line: TfrxLineView;
begin
   // Band
   band := (report.Report.FindObject('ReportBand') as TfrxReportTitle);
   // Lines generation
   left := 3;
   nol := 5;
   for i := 1 to nol do begin
      line := TfrxLineView.Create(band);
      line.CreateUniqueName;
      line.Top   := 0.73;
      line.Width := fr1cm * 2;
      line.Left  := left;
      left := left + line.Width + 30;
   end;
   // Report preview
   report.ShowReport(False);
end;
```

Comment: That helped, I already have the report on a file and therefore I use the script feature of FastReport so things turned slightly different. Of course, i didn't need to create one child for each line. That was just my old simple solution where I had to add a high number of childs with one line. Then I made all childs invisible and then, in a loop, turned visibility on up to the needed number. It was not a satisfactory solution so I'm very happy with this new solution. But I can not use the CreateUniqueName function in the script. Can anyone tell me why? I use FR5.

Comment: @larand I'm using FR4.3, but I think that `CreateUniqueName` is not a valid call inside the report, only in Delphi code. Thanks